# Joomla JInput default value

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

If I grab a value from my form in my controller using:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$add_name = $jinput->get('name', 'Default name', 'STRING');
```

I expect the default value to be set as a string called `Default name`.

But if I test this it doesn't seem to think there is a value:

```
if (!empty($add_name))
{
    //do stuff
    //I expect to be here because $add_name="Default name"
}
else
{
    //I actually go here
}
```

Am I misunderstanding the default value?

**EDIT**

If a form is submitted with an empty string then that is what will be returned. I understand that (now). But under what circumstance will the default value `Default name` ever get assigned to `$add_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submitted an empty string in your form, then it's used instead of the default value. JInput does `isset()` check, not `empty()`, so empty string is considered as a valid value.

Comment: Thanks. So when/how does the default value get applied?

Comment: I've seen that question, I asked it ;) But you explain about empty strings. My question is when will the value `Default name` ever get assigned to `$add_name`. I'll try to make the question more clear.

Comment: Sorry, working very late, I barely see on my eyes... Default value will be assigned if, for example, you submit a form without `'name'` input field